# Cypress with BDD Cucumber how to create my own data type

Tags: cucumber, cypress, bdd, cypress-cucumber-preprocessor, user-defined-data-types

I am using cypress with cucumber-js and i need to define my own data type. I did exactly same things like is described in https://github.com/TheBrainFamily/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor#custom-parameter-type-resolves.

That means:
cypress > support > step_definitions > customParameterTypes.js
I wrote:

```
const blogType = ["sport", "gaming"]

defineParameterType({
    name: "blogType",
    regexp: new RegExp(blogType.join("|"))
})
```

and in my BDD .feature file i have:

```
Given I have empty blog
And  Blog has default structure for sport
```

and in my cypress file:

```
Given(' Blog has default structure for {blogType}', blogType => {...})
```

When i start my test i get:

```
The following error originated from your test code, not from Cypress.

  > Undefined parameter type {blogType}

When Cypress detects uncaught errors originating from your test code it will automatically fail the current test.

Cypress could not associate this error to any specific test.
```

Comment: Inside your `defineParameterType()`, you are using `.join()` on `steps`, but I don't see `steps` declared in the code you've shared.

Comment: @PeaceAndQuiet ah... sorry... it was mistake just from copying from code... edited... but it is still same problem.

Answer (score 0):

For some reasons, I've had problems using `defineParameterType()` in the past, and am now using regexp in all my BDD projects.

In your `.js` file:

```js
Given(/^Blog has default structure for (sport|gaming)$/, blogType => {...});
```

Using the above, you won't need `customParameterTypes.js` and your `.feature` file stays the same.

Comment: Yeah.. But when i need that type for more steps and i am not sure That There will be only 2 options of That type... Then it will be so annoying to write it as regexp still over and over again